# nginx server setup issue

Tags: linux, centos, nginx, virtualhost

I have to setup Kayako server on a centOS 6.3 machines.. I installed nginx with php5.3 and other required stuff, everything is working. So I copied kayako files to:

```
/var/www/nginx-default/kayako/setup
```

and edited my virtual host as(full file):

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  XXX.XXX.com;

    location /kayako {
        root   /var/www/nginx-default/;
        index  index.php;
    }
}
```

Then when i use browser to hit my domain: http://XXX.XXX.com/kayako/setup/ it starts to download a file name "downlaod" and displays nothing.

and my error log file is blank..

Please tell me what is going wrong?

vi nginx.conf:

```
user              nginx;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  2;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: Nothing to serve PHP files: php-fpm, spawn-fcgi, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup PHP-FPM and start daemon.

Then add proper server and PHP sections to nginx configuration (very short example of PHP section):

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Other examples you may find on http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration